# Compare list of shapefile field names located in two separate dictionaries with same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arcpy

I created two dictionaries, d1 and d2, and both contain the same key. The key is a file path to a shapefile, for example: `C:\TestFolder\Folder1\A\address_pt.shp.` In addition, d1 has values that are lists of field names contained within the attribute table of the shapefile.

Below is an example of d1 output:

```
{
    'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\A\\address_pt.shp': [
        'FID', 'SHAPE', 'FULL_ADDRE', 'STREET_ADD', 'CITY_ST_ZI', 'PREFIX_DIR', 
        'HALF_ADDRE', 'HOUSE_NUMB', 'STREET_NAM', 'STREET_TYP', 'SUFFIX_DIR', 
        'UNIT_TYPE', 'UNIT_ID', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ZIPCODE', 'PARCEL_NUM', 
        'PARCEL_N_1', 'HOUSE_NU_1', 'HOUSE_NU_2', 'STATUS', 'ASSEMBLY_S', 'SENATE',
        'DISTRICT', 'COUNCIL', 'GRIDNUM', 'PHYSICAL_A', 'PUBDATE'
    ], 
    'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\B\\ADDRESS_VALID_POINTS.shp': [
        'FID', 'SHAPE', 'ADD_ID', 'HSE_NUMB', 'SNAM_PREMO', 'SNAM_PREDI', 'SNAME',
        'SNAM_POSTY', 'SNAM_POSDI', 'SNAM_POSMO', 'FULL_STREE', 'SUB_ADD_TY', 
        'SUB_ADD_ID', 'FULL_ADDRE', 'PLACE_NAME', 'FNSB_COMM', 'FECC_COMM',
        'ZIPCODE', 'ADD_TYPE', 'NOTES', 'STATUS', 'MS_EXCEPTI', 'NO_MSAG', 
        'GLOBALID', 'CREATED_US', 'CREATED_DA', 'LAST_EDITE', 'LAST_EDI_1'
    ], 
    'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\E\\Public_Safety_Addresses.shp': [
        'FID', 'SHAPE', 'OBJECTID', 'P_ID', 'ACCOUNT', 'TAXID_LOKI', 'ADRSNUM', 
        'P_ROADNME', 'ROADNME', 'S_ROADNME', 'PS_ROADNME', 'ADRSNUM_S', 'ZIP', 
        'LAT', 'LONG', 'ADDRESS', 'COMMUNITY', 'GLOBALID'
    ]
}
```

Furthermore, d2 contains a list of field names that are thought to be within the shapefile. Below is an example of d2. Notice that both dictionaries have the same key.

```
{
    'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\A\\address_pt.shp': [
        'HOUSE_NUMB', 'HALF_ADDRE', 'PREFIX_DIR', 'STREET_NAM', 'STREET_TYP', 
        'SUFFIX_DIR', 'UNIT_TYPE', 'UNIT_ID', ' BUILDINGA', 'STREET_ADD', 'CITY', 
        'STATE', 'ZIPCODE'
    ], 
    'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\B\\ADDRESS_VALID_POINTS.shp': [
        'HSE_NUMB', ' PRETYPEA', 'FULL_STREE', 'SUB_ADD_TY', 'SUB_ADD_ID', 'ZIPCODE'
    ], 
    'C:\\TestFolder\\Folder1\\E\\Public_Safety_Addresses.shp': [
        ' TYPEA', 'OBJECTID', 'ADRSNUM', 'P_ROADNME', 'ROADNME', 'S_ROADNME',
        'ADRSNUM_S', 'ADDRESS', 'COMMUNITY', 'ZIP'
    ]
}
```

My goal is to use the list of field names in d2 and search through d1 to see if field names from d2 exist in d1. I want to create two new dictionaries with the same keys, newd1 will contain field names found and newd2 will contain fields names not found.

In addition, I would like to capture the results of the search and input the results into two new empty fields. The first field would be named something like field_found and include the matching fields found in both dictionaries. The second field would be named something like fields_not_found and include the fields from dictionarytwo that are not found in dictionaryone.

I'm not sure if this process is possible and I can't figure out the code logic. I'm not sure if using dictionaries is the best approach. Below is the code that I currently have and it creates both dictionaries.

```
import arcpy

#Define the Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\TestFolder"

dbf1 = "APExistOnlyEdit.dbf"
myfield = "FI_PATH"

filepathlist2 =[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf1,myfield)]
#print(filepathlist2)

#Dictionary one holding Field Names that are within Shapefile
d1 = {}

for thisFile in filepathlist2:
    ContainedFieldNames = [f.name.upper() for f in arcpy.ListFields(thisFile)]
    d1[thisFile] = ContainedFieldNames

print(d1)

#Dictionary two holding Field Names that are thought to be in Shapefile
d2 = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dbf1, [
    myfield,'AP_FIPS','AP_BLDGCOM','AP_TYPE','AP_STATUS','AP_ID','AP_HOUSENU',
    'AP_HALFADD', 'AP_PREDIR','AP_PRETYPE','AP_STNAME','AP_SUFTYPE','AP_SUFDIR',
    'AP_UNITTYP','AP_UNIT','AP_BUILDIN','AP_FULLADD','AP_CITY','AP_STATE','AP_ZIP'
]) as rows:
    for row in rows:    
        d2[row[0]] = [a.upper() for a in row[1:] if a.strip() != '']

print(d2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do something like:

```py
for filepath in d1:
    newd2 = [attribute for attribute in d1.filepath if attribute not in d2.filepath]
    newd1 = [attribute for attribute in d2.filepath if attribute not in d1.filepath]
    # Do something with new & old attributes
```

Comment: Sorry never marked as helpful, thanks for sending me in the right direction. I ended up using ```for key in d1:
    diff[key] = list(set(d2[key])-set(d1.get(key,[])))```